# Some joomla versions not running in latest xampp environment

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-2.5, xampp

Hi I backed up a joomla 3.0 site from production server with database backup too. I was using xampp 1.8 version which is old and everything was fine when i set up that joomla site under xampp(localhost) development environment(as normally everyone know the process that i first import the backed up db to a new db and link that db modifying joomla config file..then i put all files under htdocs/joomla3 folder..).

But now i installed xampp latest version 7.1... or 5.6...and when i set up that joomla site and run it like http://localhost/joomla3 i see error that this page not working.when i went for admin login i see just login boxes with no styles and login not works.

I turned off display errors in php.ini but no results.When i set display errors to maximum in joomla config file i see some notice errors like that codes deprecated in that joomla library files and other notice errors mostly. If i do a fresh joomla 3.7 install then things ok so What is wrong when i restore a backed up joomla site or install old joomla 3 versions in xampp latest version ? same behavior happens for joomla 2.5 sites too.

Comment: I never used xampp, but joomla versions < 3.6 aren't PHP7.x compatible. I would suggest to update the joomla version to the latest one; afterwards update php from 5.x to 7.x / or use the latest xampp. Check your configuration files of php and apache2 as well.

Comment: So u use wamp where this kind of problems do not happen?

Comment: No, usually I separately install apache2, or nginx, mysql and php. I use different settings, most with debian, a development system with lmdb, and at home three systems with arch linux. In addition I have a provider with BSD and apache2, ther I have problems with Joomla's caching, but swithced off.  I would setup the mysql first, then apache2 make a test side, then install php either as apache module, better php-fpm; make test with phpinfo() in a file, if it works, then install Joomla at last.

Comment: Likely it's a system requirements incompatibility. The latest xampp possibly comes with latest php versions (7.x) and the sites you are restoring are not php 7 compatible.

Comment: Well xampp setup with debugging excellent for dev but i am also thinking separate installation of php, mysql, apache, @Tom let me know easy processes to save times. I am also thinking to go back to the old xampp for ease of dev so is i guess i am not missing latest php version much.

Comment: I even installed apache, mysql, php separately but no progress, i see same errors!